# Scala: Optional type parameter?

Tags: scala, generics

I wrote a method like this:

```
def typeOnly[T, S](seq: Seq[S]): Seq[T] = {
  seq.flatMap{
    case t: T => Some(t)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

And I hope to invoke it this way:

```
typeOnly[String](List(1, "2", 3, "4"))
```

It doesn't work. I seems to have to specify the second type parameter `S`:

```
typeOnly[String, Any](List(1, "2", 3, "4"))
```

But why? Shouldn't the compiler know the fact that `List(1, "2", 3, "4")` is a `Seq[Any]`?

Comment: Compiler **can** infer the fact that `List(1, "2", 3, "4")` is `Seq[Any]`, but it cannot live with a thought that you negligently forgot to specify second type. Note, that your matching is useless, since Seq type is erased at runtime.

Comment: Well, you're right. Is it possible to rewrite this method with Class Type?

Comment: If you are willing to be typesafe, you might consider using `HLists` instead of `Lists`. Implementation from [shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/) has a method (`filter`), which does what you want. [Example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/hlist.scala#L604-L632).

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR

Use this for Scala 2.9.x :

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any])(implicit m : Manifest[T]) : Seq[T] = { 
    seq.collect { 
        case t if m.erasure.isInstance(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}

scala> typeOnly[String](List(1,2,"3",4))
res1: Seq[String] = List(3)
```

and this for Scala 2.10.x :

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any])(implicit tag : scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) = { 
    seq.collect { 
        case t if tag.runtimeClass.isInstance(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}
```

---

As `Seq` is defined as `trait Seq[+A]` (the key is the `+`), any `Seq[S]` is also a `Seq[Any]`.

On the other hand, as it has already been said, T is "forgotten" when the function is compiled, so you can't use it directly. You must pass the Class of T as a parameter, some how.

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any], c : Class[T]) : Seq[T] = { 
    seq.flatMap { 
        case t if c.isInstance(t) => Some(t.asInstanceOf[T])
        case _ => None 
    }
}
```

In Scala, appart from `Class[T]`, there are also `Manifest[T]`, which is a bit more powerful, and, as a consequence, more idiomatic. In particular, it has a method `erasure` which returns a `Class[T]`. Using it, you could go and write your function like this:

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any], m : Manifest[T]) : Seq[T] = { 
    seq.flatMap { 
        case t if m.erasure.isInstance(t) => Some(t.asInstanceOf[T])
        case _ => None 
    }
}
```

It seems that we have gained nothing. However, if you ask the compiler nicely (using `implicit`), it will pass the `Manifest` for you when you call the function.

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any])(implicit m : Manifest[T]) : Seq[T] = { 
    seq.flatMap { 
        case t if m.erasure.isInstance(t) => Some(t.asInstanceOf[T])
        case _ => None 
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> typeOnly[java.lang.Integer](List(1,2,"3",4))
res2: Seq[java.lang.Integer] = List(1, 2, 4)

scala> typeOnly[String](List(1,2,"3",4))
res3: Seq[String] = List(3)

scala> typeOnly[java.lang.Double](List(1,2,"3",4))
res4: Seq[java.lang.Double] = List()
```

There are more alternatives, some of them yet more idiomatic. You could, for example, 
use `collect` with a partially-defined function:

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any])(implicit m : Manifest[T]) : Seq[T] = { 
    seq.collect { 
        case t if m.erasure.isInstance(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}
```

*WARNING*: The former examples work in **Scala 2.9.3** and below. If you are developing for **Scala 2.10.x**, `Manifest#erasure` has been deprecated. Use `runtimeClass` instead:

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any])(implicit m : Manifest[T]) = { 
    seq.collect { 
        case t if m.runtimeClass.isInstance(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}
```

As manifests will soon be deprecated too (see comment below), you should consider using a ClassTag.

```
def typeOnly[T](seq : Seq[Any])(implicit tag : scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) = { 
    seq.collect { 
        case t if tag.runtimeClass.isInstance(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in Scala 2.10, you should prefer `TypeTag` over `Manifest`. `Manifest` is planned to be deprecated. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html#typetags_and_manifests

Answer (score 3):

Your `case t: T => Some(t)` does not filter the elements by type `T`.  What you need is something like this:

```
  def typeOnly[T](seq: Seq[Any], clazz: Class[T] = classOf[Any]): Seq[T] = {
    seq.flatMap{
      case t: T if clazz.isInstance(t) => Some(t)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

Which you invoke like this:

```
typeOnly(Seq(1, "2", 3))
typeOnly(Seq(1, "2", 3), classOf[String])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming at allowing `typeOnly`  users to only specify the `T` type parameter, you could define it this way:

```
def typeOnly[S](seq: Seq[S]) = new {
  def apply[T]: Seq[T] =
    seq.flatMap{
      case t: T => Some(t)
      case _ => None
    }
}
```

You would have to call it this way

```
val l = typeOnly(List(1, "2", 3, "4"))[String]
```

(notice the type parameter after the argument instead of just after `typeOnly`).

This adds a compiler warning because of its particular use of structural types. If you want to avoid adding an `import language.reflectiveCalls` to fix that, you can rely on an intermediate class:

```
case class TypeOnlyFilter[S](seq: Seq[S]) {
  def apply[T]: Seq[T] =
    seq.flatMap{
      case t: T => Some(t)
      case _ => None
    }
}

def typeOnly[S](seq: Seq[S]) =
  new TypeOnlyFilter(seq)
```

Note that this implementation still has a compiler warning about the unchecked abstract type pattern T (as your original implementation does). You just have to require a `ClassTag` for type `T` to fix that, so that the final solution looks like:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class TypeOnlyFilter[S](seq: Seq[S]) {
  def apply[T: ClassTag]: Seq[T] =
    seq.flatMap{
      case t: T => Some(t)
      case _ => None
    }
}

def typeOnly[S](seq: Seq[S]) =
  new TypeOnlyFilter(seq)
```